# How to create a node in c#

Tags: c#, c

I am new to c# and switched from c to c#. I want to do equivalent of c to c#. The same i have in c like this:

```
  temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

where Node is:

```
struct Node 
{
    unsigned int symbol ;            
    int freq;
    struct Node * next,  * left, * right;   
}
```

And in c# i have used `class` instead of `struct`.
I tried to do this way:

```
 Node temp = new Node();
```

Where `Node` is same except that it's a class and used public (I am sure that's correct).
Could you please help me if i am wrong ? Does it correctly create a node equivalent to that i created using malloc() ?

Comment: What's the exception? By the way, please don't do this in C#. Using pointers is a sign you are going down the wrong path.

Comment: Why do you need an *equivalent* for something that exists by itself? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? What's your C# code for the Node class? What does "correctly" mean to you?

Comment: @poncha Don't assume that because a `struct` is used in C that a `struct` is the correct approach in C# (and if you're not assuming that, avoid making comments that imply it).

Comment: A couple of issues - firstly can you show the definition of `Node` in your C# code, and secondly it isn't really clear what your question is?

Comment: @LordTakkera - You're correct, but he said he implemented it as a class in C#. His C# isn't there, but I'd assume he used references instead of pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class should look something like

```
public class Node
{
    public unsigned int symbol;
    public int freq;
    public Node next;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
}
```

If you assign to `next`, `left`, and `right` similar to

```
Node root = new Node();
root.next = new Node();
```

You will see behavior very similar to what you were doing in C.

Storage is automatically managed by the runtime, so there are no explicit calls to equivalents of `malloc` or `free`.  That all happens behind the scenes.

Also, as a general rule do not use pointers in C#.  While you *can* do that if you mark your code as *unsafe*, there are very few instances where *unsafe* code is the right path for a C# app.

NOTE: The example uses public access to the class and fields.  You may want to restrict that somewhat based on your specific use.

Comment: It sounded to me like he made everything public, which is probably what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me.

As an added bonus, it will also call `Node()`'s constructor if you have one and initialize the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node 
{
    public int symbol ;
    public int freq;
    public Node next;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node temp = new Node() ;
        temp.symbol = 1;
        temp.freq = 2;
        temp.next = null;
    }
}
```